# edit part of text in text file using batch

Tags: batch-file

i've got a file like this:

```
N1 G17 G90
N3 G54
N5 S24000
N7 M03
N9 G00 X2675.766 Y427.409 Z730
N11 G00 X2675.766 Y427.409
N13 G00 X2675.766 Y427.409
N15 G00 X2675.766 Y427.409 Z505
N17 F4000
N19 G01 X2675.766 Y427.409 Z447.5
N21 F4000
N23 G01 X2565.966 Y475.823 Z447.5
N25 F4000
N27 G02 X1852.832 Y871.38 Z447.5 I4373.42 J4575.032
N29 G03 X705.065 Y871.38 Z447.5 I1278.948 J28.138
N31 G02 X-8.069 Y475.823 Z447.5 I-1815.523 J4575.032
N33 M05
N35 M30
```

X and Y can be a normal number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc) or a decimal number (1.134, 106.304, etc)
I i'm looking for a way to add a specified number to X and/or Y.
the added number is the same for evry line.
if i add 100 to X all lines with  X should changes to the X(number + 100).
same goes for Y

X, Y, Z, I, J aren't always there
sometimes it is just 
X, Y or X, Y, Z or X, Y, I, J

So to put evrything together
i need a batch file where i can add a specified number to every number after X or Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-4*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%d" equ "" (
      echo %%a %%b %%c
   ) else (
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=X." %%C in ("%%c") do (
         set /A X=%%C+200
         if "%%D" neq "" set "X=!X!.%%D"
      )
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=Y." %%D in ("%%d") do (
         set /A Y=%%D+100
         if "%%E" neq "" set "Y=!Y!.%%E"
      )
      echo %%a %%b X!X! Y!Y! %%e
   )
)
```

Comment: theres missing a "(" before the "for" statement and ")" at the end.
but its works!!!! your a life saviour!!!!!

Comment: if you have any experience with C#. could  you take a look at this then? :) its the same that i need only in a different language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261960/edit-part-of-text-in-text-file-using-c-sharp